# How to get Spark app handle by app ID in java

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I submit spark application by spark launcher. I would not wait until the application completed, but need to make way to kill application.

```
SparkAppHandle spark = new SparkLauncher()
            .setAppResource("/usr/local/myapp.jar")
            .setMainClass("com.myapp.app")
            .setMaster("yarn")
            .setDeployMode( "cluster")
            .startApplication( this);
```

and get app id.

```
String id = spark.getAppId(); // how to wait untill not UNKONWN?
SparkAppHandle curApp = ???.getHandleByID( id); // how to get?
```

How can I get SparkAppHnadle by App ID, so I can call destory() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method to get SparkAppHandle by other information of it. I solved it with making hashmap which has appID or unique string as key, and SparkAppHandle as value. It's not fundamental solution but it's only solution so far.